# How to properly center equation labels in itemize environment?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering, itemize

I would like to put the the first equation label at the middle of the bullets.
Here is my code

```
 \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{mathrsfs}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{amssymb}


  \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

  \begin{document}

  \noindent

Let $ a,b,c,d \in \R$ such that

\begin{itemize}

\item $c \neq 0;$ \hfill \refstepcounter{equation}\textup{  (\theequation)}\label{homographic_condition}

\item  $ad-bc \neq 0.$

\end{itemize}

Let $f: \R \setminus \left\{ -\dfrac{d}{c} \right\} \to \R$ 

be the homographic function defined by

\begin{equation}\label{homographic}

f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d} \qquad \forall\, x \neq -\dfrac{d}{c}.

\end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: Here is the output]

The desired code should put (1) at the middle.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you embed the `itemize` environment in a `minipage` environment which, in turn, should be embedded in an `equation` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Let $ a,b,c,d \in \R$ such that
\begin{equation}\label{homographic_condition}
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth} % 0.95\textwidth would be too wide
\begin{itemize}
\item $c \neq 0$;
\item  $ad-bc \neq 0$.
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{equation}
Let $f\colon \R \setminus \left\{ -\dfrac{d}{c} \right\} \to \R$ 
be the homographic function defined by
\begin{equation}\label{homographic}
f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d} \quad \forall\ x \neq -\frac{d}{c}.
\end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,varwidth}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Let $ a,b,c,d \in \R$ such that
{\makeatletter\@fleqntrue\makeatother
\begin{equation}\label{homographic_condition}
  \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item $c \neq 0$;
      \item $ad-bc \neq 0$.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{varwidth}
\end{equation}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With use `nccmath` package and its environment `fleqn` you can write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{nccmath, amssymb}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Let $ a,b,c,d \in \R$ such that
\begin{fleqn}[1em]
    \begin{equation}\label{homographic_condition}
        \begin{aligned}
    \bullet \quad & c \neq 0      \\
    \bullet \quad & ad-bc \neq 0  .
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
Let $f: \R \setminus \left\{ -\mfrac{d}{c} \right\} \to \R$ be the homographic function defined by

    \begin{equation}\label{homographic}
f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d} \qquad \forall\, x \neq -\dfrac{d}{c}.
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and get:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to create fake `\item`s using `flalign` to reach the left margin.  Note that every time you add a blank line you are adding a paragraph break.

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{mathrsfs}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{amssymb}


  \newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
  
  \parindent=0pt% an alternative to \noindent
  \parskip=\baselineskip
  
  \newsavebox{\fakeitem}
  \savebox{\fakeitem}{\makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\textbullet\hskip\labelsep}}

  \begin{document}
Let $ a,b,c,d \in \R$ such that
\begin{flalign}\label{homographic_condition}
\begin{aligned}
  \usebox\fakeitem & c \neq 0; \\
  \usebox\fakeitem & ad-bc \neq 0.
\end{aligned} &&&
\end{flalign}
Let $f: \R \setminus \left\{ -\dfrac{d}{c} \right\} \to \R$ \newline
be the homographic function defined by
\begin{equation}\label{homographic}
f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d} \qquad \forall\, x \neq -\dfrac{d}{c}.
\end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a minipage (in the form of `varwidth` so as not to guess a width) with a reduced `itemize` as far as vertical spacing is concerned. The minipage is moved to the left (but some horizontal spacing is used with `wide=1em`) with a trick that makes TeX to think that the equation is very long.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem,varwidth}

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}


Let $ a,b,c,d \in \R$ such that
\begin{equation}\label{homographic_condition}
\hspace{0pt}
\begin{varwidth}{\displaywidth}
  \begin{itemize}[nosep,wide=1em]
  \item $c \neq 0$; 
  \item $ad-bc \neq 0$,
  \end{itemize}
\end{varwidth}
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fil}
\end{equation}
and let $f\colon \R \setminus \{ -d/c \} \to \R$ be the homographic function defined by
\begin{equation}\label{homographic}
f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d} \qquad x \neq -\dfrac{d}{c}.
\end{equation}
    
\end{document}
```

I'd not use `\dfrac` that spoils the spacing: the inline fraction is as clear.

I also use `\colon` and no `\forall` (whose usage at that point is wrong, in my opinion).

[image]